# Issue with Rendering Base64 Image from POST Request in TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, base64, tcpdf

I have a base64-encoded image:

```
var croppedMap = croppedCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');
var form = document.createElement('form');
                    form.setAttribute('method', 'post');
                    form.setAttribute('action', 'pdf/generate.php');
                    form.setAttribute('target', '_blank');


var input2 = document.createElement('input');
                    input2.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
                    input2.setAttribute('name', 'MAP');
                    input2.setAttribute('value', croppedMap);
                    form.appendChild(input2);
                    document.body.appendChild(form);
                    form.submit();

                    document.body.removeChild(form);
```

I'm attempting to render it using TCPDF. I fetch this image from a POST request:

```
$mapData = isset($_REQUEST['MAP']) ? $_REQUEST['MAP'] : '';
$mapData = "@".preg_replace('#^data:image/[^;]+;base64,#', '', $mapData);
$img = '<img src="' . $mapData . '">';
```

Then, I assign the image to an HTML variable like this:

```
$html = '...<td rowspan="2" style="height: 50%;">'. $img .'</td>...';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('pdf-file.pdf', 'I');
```

But, the image isn't rendering despite confirming that it's set. When I directly set the image in the code (example: $img = '@iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0gA...'), it works. The issue seems to occur only when I retrieve it from a POST request. Any suggestions on why it's not working?

Comment: _"When I directly set the image in the code (example: $img = '@iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA0gA...'), it works. "_ - that makes no sense whatsoever - there would not even be an `<img>` _tag_ in what you are passing to the PDF writer then.

Comment: The `data:image/...;base64,` prefix is what _makes_ this a Data URI in the first place, so why are you stripping that off?

Comment: @CBroe because not supported in tcpdf it require @

Comment: Okay, but `<img src="@XYZ">` vs. _just_ `@XYZ` would still be a major, significant difference.

Comment: Have you checked what your `$mapData` actually contains - before, and after the replacing operation?

Answer (score 0):

The problem arose when the Foxit PDF Reader failed to render the image for an unknown reason, yet the image was visible when opened in a browser.